# Number of Ways to pair off equally sized sets, with some pairs restricted

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say that we have two sets of size N. Let's call those sets S and R.

As an example of what I'm trying to do,
let S be {1, 2, 3}, and let R be {A, B, C}.

A single valid paired-off result would look like this: {1B, 2A, 3C}. Each element from S and R *must be used exactly once*. Order does not matter.

If I understand correctly, there are N! possible result sets with no further restrictions.

Now let us say there is a single set of *disallowed pairs*, F. Let F be {1A, 2B, 3C}. The shape of F is not arbitrary, it will always look like this. If N were 4, F would be {1A, 2B, 3C, 4D} if S was {1, 2, 3, 4} and R was {A, B, C, D}. For a single result (for example, {1B, 2C, 3A} above) to be valid, no pair in that result may be a member of F. By this definition, the result {1B, 2A, 3C} above would be invalid, because it contains 3C which is a member of F.

In the hopes that I can clarify, I'll enumerate the possible results and mark the invalid ones with an x:

```
[
   x {1A, 2B, 3C} // contains 1A, 2B, and 3C, all disallowed
   x {1A, 2C, 3B} // contains 1A
   x {1B, 2A, 3C} // contains 3C
     {1B, 2C, 3A}
     {1C, 2A, 3B}
   x {1C, 2B, 3A} // contains 2B
]
```

Thus, there are two valid results.

Given two sets of size N, and one set of disallowed pairs (also of size N), how can I determine the number of valid results?

Some other questions:

- Does this kind of problem have a name?
- What concepts are at play here? What would be some other interesting problems to explore that might help me solve this one?

Thanks, and I appreciate the help. I am very interested in this problem but I don't have enough recent training to understand how to tackle it properly.

Comment: You're trying to count the number of "derangements."  This is a standard problem with a well known result.

Comment: See [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#:~:text=In%20combinatorial%20mathematics%2C%20a%20derangement,that%20has%20no%20fixed%20points.)

Comment: Should say:  it's hard to follow what you have written.  The usual description of a derangement is straight forward:  it is a permutation which has no fixed points.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the pointer, I'm glad to know this is a pretty standard problem with a well known result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An observation that may help with googling is that you can rephrase this problem as:

> The number of ways to reorder a set with no items staying in the same position

This is also known as a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

---

One way to derive the solution is to use a recursive argument and let $r_n$ be the number of derangements of n objects and then try to reason why $r_n = (n-1)(r_{n-1} + r_{n-2})$ (I'd encourage you to try and work this out by yourself! But if you get stuck there is a proof on the Wikipedia page for derangements)

You can then manually count the possibilities for $r_1$ and $r_2$, and then use these to deduce the formula
$$
r_n = n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
$$
Which by noting that $e^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$, can be rearranged into the very neat looking $r_n = \left[ \frac{n!}{e} \right]$ where $[\ ]$ is the nearest integer function

Comment: This is a really great explanation, thanks! I actually have an extension of this problem that I want to think about on my own for a bit, but I may be back with more questions if I get stuck.

Comment: I asked this question because it was a simplification of another problem I had in real life.

My problem is similar to the hat problem but with a twist:
If there are n people (n is even) belonging to n/2 couples with n hats, how many ways can the hats be distributed such that nobody gets their own hat AND nobody gets their spouse's hat?

Comment: This seems to make the problem substantially harder. I found a sequence corresponding to this problem in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000316)

Comment: that explains why I couldn't successfully figure out how many ways our secret santa drawing could end up. I am going to look into the references listed in that link and see if I can get anywhere on a program that generates all the valid results :) Thanks so much for that link